# How to match keys from one array to another, and return keys from the other

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have 2 arrays, I would like to use the keys from the 1st array to search for matched keys from the 2nd array and return those keys from the 2nd array 
with the values ​​of the second array.

expected result:
        Array
       (
        'Intermediary/contract/{contract:id}/bank-accounts'[2]
        'Manager/action/{action:id}/bank-bills'[2]
      )

```
 $arrayOne = [ 

 '/Intermediary/contract//bank-accounts'[2]
 '/Manager/action//bank-bills'[2]]

  $arrayTwo = [

 '/Intermediary/contract/{contract:id}/bank-accounts',
 '/Manager/action/{action:id}/bank-bills',
  ]
```

So far I've tried, among others,

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {

    $results = preg_grep('/$key/', $array2);
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: See the [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) function.

Comment: Those aren't keys.

Answer (score 1):

Those are values and not keys in your example arrays.

First get rid of all of the `{.....}` from `$arrayTwo` and compute the intersection (same entries) with `$arrayOne`.  Since the keys are preserved in the array that has been replaced you can compute the intersection of keys with `$arrayTwo`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(
    array_intersect(preg_replace('/\{[^}]+\}/', '', $arrayTwo), $arrayOne),
    $arrayTwo
);
```

Here's a [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gl00j).

If you really need the keys then the answer is slightly different getting the keys as an array:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(
    array_keys($arrayTwo),
    array_intersect(preg_replace('/\{[^}]+\}/', '', array_keys($arrayTwo)),
                                                    array_keys($arrayOne))
);
```

Here's a [Demo](https://3v4l.org/nj5aq).

To do it with a loop:

```
foreach($arrayTwo as $k => $v) {
    if(in_array(preg_replace('/\{[^}]+\}/', '', $k), array_keys($arrayOne))) {
        $result[] = $k;
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason you need them as keys again, there is [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

Comment: I simplified the example, these keys have values, but I omitted them. I would like to get:'/Intermediary/contract/{contract:id}/bank-accounts',
 '/Manager/action/{action:id}/bank-bills',

Comment: I edited, but in the future, changing keys to values and omitting the keys is not _simplified_.

Comment: I would like the keys in the first table to be replaced with matching keys from the second table, while the values ​​remain the same in the first table.

Comment: Output:   $result [ 

 '/Intermediary/contract/{contract:id}/bank-accounts'[2]
 '/Manager/action/{action:id}/bank-bills'[2]]